# Why is git --date=format: ignoring %Z

Tags: git, date-formatting

```
> date "+%a %b %d %H:%M:%S%Z %Y"
Thu Nov 03 21:03:55 GMT 2022
> git --version
git version 2.35.3
> git "--no-pager" show "-date=format:%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z %Y" -s "--format=from commit %H of %ad"
from commit 8c440202fbf07363e67af9b9d24a910a50ece0f7 of Thu Nov 03 18:54:20  2022
```

Why is the time zone missing?

Answer (score 3):

Because Git doesn't have the information you want.  `%Z` is the timezone name or abbreviation, but Git only stores a Unix epoch and a timezone offset.  An example is `1667436375 +0000`.

We don't know what timezone that's in.  It could be someone who's using `Etc/UTC` (abbreviation `UTC`), `Etc/GMT`, `Atlantic/Reykjavik`, `Europe/London` (`GMT`), or `Europe/Lisbon` (`WST`), among others.  In general, it's nearly impossible to go from an offset from an actual timezone name because, unsurprisingly, many jurisdictions are typically covered by the same time zone and they often don't agree on what to call it (in part because they often don't share a language).

Because Git synthesizes the timestamp itself from the commit, it can't use `TZ` or other information to acquire the time zone, and as such, it won't be printed.  You can use `%z` instead for a numeric offset.